# How to position SVG image coming from SVG's <use>

Tags: css, svg, css-position, css-transforms

I have an SVG which is kind of group photo containing 12 characters. The SVG also contains the positioning of these characters in the group photo. Each single character has an `id`. Now using SVG's [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) I would like to reuse these single characters in another part of the page.

Like this:

[image]

Notice the head showing in the bottom left of the upper image. As you can see the positioning is not working. I already tried setting `top`, `left`, `position: absolute`, `translate(0, 0)` -- but no success.

Actually it should look like this:
[image]

I've set up a [codepen](https://codepen.io/nachtigall/full/brbGEg/) where you can see the issue. Any idea to get this working?

Comment: We need a **minimal** example...preferably in a Stack Snippet not a full rendering of the entire page in a link.

Comment: hmm, well, I agree. OTOH the problem is mostly visible due to the big SVG having position in it. So i thought that with looking with the DevTool's Inspector might be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this style

```
.st-infobox__img svg use {
    transform:  translate(-300px, -100px);
}
```

[corrected codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxYmOx)

Comment: Thx, for looking into it also the given code was really neither perfect nor minimal!